# Enforce uniqueness of custom field

Tags: custom-fields, hooks

I created a custom field on groups, which contains a string. When this string is not empty, I want it to be unique. What is the preferred way to do this? Should I implement a hook?

Answer (score 2):

I think a hook's the way to go.  For non-custom fields you can specify this a little more easily in the XML definition of the field, but for a custom field, I think the hook is your best best.

I think I'd use `hook_validateForm` or `hook_pre`.  The first is more user-friendly, but since it's at the form level you have to identify everywhere the field can be edited.  It's a fairly easy hook to write though - just make an API "get" call to CustomValue with that value and see if you get a count > 0.

Comment: Thanks! The documentation of [hook_pre](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_pre) says 'This hook does not allow the abort of the operation, use a form hook instead.' So I guess I will go for `hook_validateForm`.

Comment: On the other hand, this will not prevent setting duplicate values using the API...

Comment: It's true that it won't abort the operation - but you CAN modify the values to ensure a bad value isn't written.